# How to check if an array contains sequential, evenly spaced numbers?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating a program to determine who wins a game of poker.

For context, the input data was in the format:

```
8C TS KC 9H 4S 7D 2S 5D 3S AC
```

Where the first character indicates the strength of the card (A = Ace, T = 10, J = Jack etc) and the second indicates the suit. The first 5 cards are player one and the last 5 are player two.

The data has been read into an array, split into two arrays containing each player's hands, playerOneHands and playerTwoHands. Then this array is further split into an array describing the strengths of the cards (converting the string into integers and turning "T" into int 10, "J" into int 11 etc), playerOneCardStrengths and playerTwoCardStrengths, as well as the suits, playerOneCardSuits and playerTwoCardSuits. The strengths array was then sorted in order from highest to lowest using

```
Array.Sort(playerOneCardStrengths, playerOneCardSuits);
```

I would now like to pass these values through a function which checks whether or not a royal flush has occured. It would input these two arrays and output a boolean describing whether a royal flush had occured.

A royal flush is defined in poker as a hand containing an Ace, King, Queen, Jack and Ten all of the same suit.

This is what I have so far:

```
static bool determineRoyalFlush(int[] cardStrengths, string[] cardSuits)
    {
        bool royalFlush = false;
        if (cardSuits[0] != cardSuits[1])
        {
            return royalFlush = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (cardStrengths[0] != 14)
            {
                return royalFlush = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (cardStrengths[0] - cardStrengths[1] == 1 
                    && cardStrengths[1] - cardStrengths[2] == 1
                    && cardStrengths[2] - cardStrengths[3] == 1
                    && cardStrengths[3] - cardStrengths[4] == 1)
                {
                    return royalFlush = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    royalFlush = false;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

My two questions:

Is there a neater way to check whether whether the cardStrengths array contains sequential numbers in a number line? the last bit of code above essentially checks whether cardStrengths[0] = 14 and [1] = 13 and [2] = 12 etc. But I would like to reuse this code to check for a regular flush, and I'm just curious about how I could check, say, an array a million integers long whether or not they all count up 1 2 3 4 .. etc, or count down again.

Secondly, and more importantly, I'm getting the error "Not all code paths return a value", but I can't see any scenario where this doesn't return true or false? I'm overlooking something somewhere.

Thanks!

Comment: `return royalFlush = false;` always returns `false` because it uses the assignment operator instead of the equals operator (`==`). But `return !royalFlush;` is better than `return royalFlush == false;` and `return royalFlush;` is better than `return royalFlush == true;`. You want to return either `true` or `false` and since `royalFlush` already contains the desired value, you can return it directly. There is no need to compare it with `== true`.

Answer (score 0):

*To Solve Your Second Question* :

Your last else statement `(royalFlush = False )` does not return anything . Changing the code to `return False` should it .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to compare the items to the previous ones by starting the loop with the second one (i.e. with index 1 instead of 0).

```
if (cardStrengths[0] != 14) {
    return false;
}
for (int i = 1; i < cardStrengths.Length; i++) {
    if (cardStrengths[i - 1] - cardStrengths[i] != 1) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

The variable `royalFlush` is not needed.

---

It would add much clarity if you structured the game by adding some types representing the concepts of the game

```
public enum Suit
{
    Club,
    Diamond,
    Heart,
    Spade
}

public enum Rank
{
   Two = 2, Three = 3, Four = 4, Five = 5, Six = 6, Seven = 7, Eight = 8, Nine = 9, Ten = 10,
   Jack = 11, Queen = 12, King = 13, Ace = 14
}
```

Comparing with `rank == Rank.Ace` is more understandable than comparing `rank == 14`.

Cards could be represented like this:

```
public class Card
{
    public Rank Rank { get; }
    public Suit Suit { get; }

    public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit)
    {
        Rank = rank;
        Suit = suit;
    }

    public Card(string s)
    {
        switch (s[0]) {
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':
                Rank = (Rank)(s[0] - '0');
                break;
            case 'T':
                Rank = Rank.Ten;
                break;
            case 'J':
                Rank = Rank.Jack;
                break;
            case 'Q':
                Rank = Rank.Queen;
                break;
            case 'K':
                Rank = Rank.King;
                break;
            case 'A':
                Rank = Rank.Ace;
                break;
        }
        switch (s[1]) {
            case 'C':
                Suit = Suit.Club;
                break;
            case 'D':
                Suit = Suit.Diamond;
                break;
            case 'H':
                Suit = Suit.Heart;
                break;
            case 'S':
                Suit = Suit.Spade;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I added 2 constructors. One allows you to define a card directly by specifying the values. The other one parses a string like `"8C"` and converts it to corresponding values.

A `Hand` class allows you to put the scoring methods somewhere and to abstract from bare arrays. Here again 2 constructors.

```
public class Hand
{
    public Hand(params Card[] cards)
    {
        Cards = cards;
    }

    public Hand(string s)
    {
        // E.g. s = "8C TS KC 9H 4S"
        string[] parts = s.Split();
        Cards = parts
            .Select(p => new Card(p))
            .ToArray();
    }

    public Card[] Cards { get; }

    public bool IsRoyalFlush()
    {
        if (Cards[0].Rank != Rank.Ace) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < Cards.Length; i++) {
            if (Cards[i - 1].Rank - Cards[i].Rank != 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    //TODO: Add more scoring methods.
}
```

On [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) the user [Glitch](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/160246/glitch) presented an already very well-structured game ([2048 console game (C#)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188273/2048-console-game-c)).

[In my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/188275/9810) I suggested even more structure by separating different aspects of the game. It first seems like more works, but once you have established a good structure, it is much easier to work on the code.